# Chromedriver in docker container not accepting remote connections even with whitelist IP's

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On my local network, I have started a docker container that installs chrome/chromedriver but the whitelist option is not working and it is rejecting all connections.

```
# Use an official Debian runtime as a parent image
FROM debian:buster-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=95.0.4638.54
ENV GOOGLE_CHROME_VERSION=95.0.4638.69-1

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yqq unzip curl wget gnupg libglib2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4 libfontconfig1 libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1 libxi6 libxrandr2 libasound2 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 xdg-utils libgbm1 && \
    wget -O /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${GOOGLE_CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb || apt-get install -fy && \
    rm /tmp/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

# Allow ChromeDriver to accept connections from all network interfaces
CMD ["chromedriver", "--whitelisted-ips="]

# Expose port 9515
EXPOSE 9515
```

But it fails whenever I try to connect with my client with this error:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1688671518.049][SEVERE]: Rejecting request with host: 192.168.29.5:9515 address: 192.168.29.5
```

Note that this error also happens when running on 127.0.0.0. Why is the whitelist ip option which is allowing all IP's not working?